# Netbeans maven-surefire-plugin not generating HTML

Tags: java, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

How can I run 'mvn'.

I'm using Netbeans 7 and when I run my Unit tests, I do get generated XML files from my project /target folder

/target/surefire-reports/TEST-package.name.ClassNameTest.xml

/target/surefire-reports/TEST-package.name.ClassNameTest.txt

But from all the xml and txt files from my test packages,

I can't figure out how to generate a HTML Report.

I'm currently using a Maven Netbeans Project. Here is my pom.xml file:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.10</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>  
</dependencies>
<groupId>com.honeycomb</groupId>
<artifactId>com.honeycomb</artifactId>

<!-- To use the report goals in your POM or parent POM -->  
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10</version>
            <configuration>
                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

I can get my tests to pass fine, I use the built in Unit Runner with Junit4 in Netbeans.

I have googled all over the place, all I find is poorly documented examples and not a complete walkthrough on how to generate a report HTML file with my test outcomes.

Not sure if this is relevant but Im developing under Windows XP. JDK 7. The Maven I use is straight out of the Netbeans Project.

I have seen posts and examples through using:

http://maven.apache.org/maven-1.x/plugins/junit-report/goals.html

junit-report:report and junit-report but I can't seem to figure out any of this stuff.

Just looking for a simple generated HTML file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run the command `mvn surefire-report:report`, then you should find a file called `target/site/surefire-report.html` gets generated after surefire runs your tests again.

If you're just running from the command-line, then I think this will get you what you want.  If you're using a CI server like Jenkins or Hudson, then I would suggest looking into the Sonar server and its reports.